# Toggle button, show and hide an element, but move button simultaneously

Tags: jquery, css, html, toggle, switch-statement

I have a toggle button using this code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#MyToggleSwitch').live('click', function(event) { 

             jQuery('.ElementToHideAndShow').toggle('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I now want to move the #MyToggleSwitch down 50px when the button is pressed to hide the element, and then move it back up 50px to show the element....Think like a lightswitch. I also want to change the color of the button when its pressed. How do I do this? And how do I make the page load with the element hidden first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on why you need to move your button down to hide it.  Does [this work](http://jsfiddle.net/mNMyb/1/) for you? Also, if you are only hiding 1 element, why is it a class and not an id?

**Edit:** something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/mNMyb/2/)?

**Edit:** here's [one that animates](http://jsfiddle.net/mNMyb/4/). However, colors cannot be animated with animate().  There are probably plug-ins out there that can do this, however.

Comment: Im not trying to hide the button. I want the button act like a light switch, hence the moving up and down. And its a class, because the element exist in multiple places simultaneously, and I want them all hidden and shown at once.

Comment: I updated my post to have another link.  Maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: Is there a way for me to make the button position ease on click instead of being instant?

Comment: On it.  Give me a moment, mate!

Comment: Done.  It's unfortunate, but jQuery by default cannot animate colors.

Comment: I just remember something... the hidden part on page load.  Could you explain that if you still want it implemented?